# error: cannot convert 'char**' to 'char*' in initialization for strings

Tags: c, pointers, char

I am making C console menu program.
And I am stuck with the char* assignment.
Is there any good method to assign char* to char**?
The code is as below:

```
       char* group0[14]=
{
//group0:5
"Funciton0-1",
"Function0-2",
"Funciton0-3",
"Function0-4",
"Funciton0-5",
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
};

//... group0~group9 are similiar.

   char* group9[14]=
{
//group9:2
"Funciton9-1",
"Function9-2",
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
};

    char* name[10][14]=
{
{group0},
{group1},
{group2},
{group3},
{group4},
{group5},
{group6},
{group7},
{group8},
{group9},
};
```

Why can't I assign those group into this "name" array?
The compiler replies me error...

Thank you!

Comment: What char* assignment? What char**? This code contains neither. And no, you can't assign a char*  to a char** or vice versa because they are different, non-compatible types, pointing at different things.

Comment: My purpose is to put 1D char array to 2D one. (as you can see group0~9 to name)  It seems the type is different, but I take my assignment should be OK...

Comment: `char* name[10][14]` is not the same as `char** name[10]`. In your initializer list `{group0}` is same as `{group0, 0, 0, 0...}`as you are initializing arrays.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `group0` in the initializer list of `name`, it will [decay to pointer to first element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/694733). This means that for expression `group0`, the type will be of `&group0[0]`, which is `char**`.

Assuming that `name` supposed to be array of pointers to groups, you need to change it's type accordingly:

```
char** name[10] = {
    group0,
    group1,
     ...
```

Comment: More correct would be to use array pointers `char* (*name)[10] = { &group0, group1, ... };`.

Comment: @Lundin Did you mean `char* (*name[10])[14] = { &group0, ...`? I considered that, but I don't think that gives much practical benefit given the complex syntax it brings with it.

Comment: Actually I mean `char* (*name)[14]`. No complicated syntax, `name[i]` gives array pointer number `i`, `name[i][j]` gives char* number `j`.

Comment: @Lundin I don't think that's enough. `name` needs to be array of 10 elements, if groups 1-9 should fit in.

Comment: Ah you are right. So it should indeed be `char* (*name[10])[14] `.